# What is ROSPACK_MAKEDIST

Tags: ros, stack, cmake, rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I see

```
set(ROSPACK_MAKEDIST true)
```

in some CMakeLists.txt files at the stack level, but I can't find information about it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9670/what-is-rospack_makedist/) by [Benoit Larochelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/216/benoit-larochelle/) on ROS Answers with karma: 867 on 2011-04-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That variable is no longer needed, and can safely be deleted from any `CMakeLists.txt` file where you find it.

There was a time when `ROSPACK_MAKEDIST` was needed to elicit stack-specific behavior from `rosbuild`, but it was [removed long ago](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/changeset/7768).

---

Originally posted by [Brian Gerkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/8/brian-gerkey/) with karma: 2916 on 2011-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3